# Wi-Fi discconects shortly after router reset

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.
On windows, wi-fi works fine with high speed.
On Ubuntu however, it's very slow that I can't open any website, and disconnects and reconnects again often.
When I restart my router, the wi-fi works for 10 to 15 minutes and then the issue starts all over.

Here is my wireless information:

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7663892/

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot

The answer comes from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110).

Comment: The problem is back again, I didn't change the system settings nor made any update.

Comment: If it worked for five days then it is not the same issue, once you accept an answer you are not suppose to unaccept it, you need to accept it again and start a new question then we will go through everything and see what happened. Post a new file in the new question from the script and it should tell us what changed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a duplicate question ?

Comment: I do not believe it is the same issue unless there were updates or driver installed that you do not know about. You said it worked for about five minutes not five days and five minutes so I believe something happened hopefully not the same driver issue that would not have happened without help from someone so we should be good to start a new question, just add a new script file and we can compare them.